# How to quickly get the list of groups a track has been contributed to?

Tags: php, soundcloud

Using the soundcloud api / php sdk I am currently forced to poll all the groups a certain user is a member of and checking if a certain track id currently exists in that group in order to validate if the track was contributed to that group or not.

Would it be too hard to add a subresource to /track that could list all the group ids that certain track is a member of?

Is there any other approach that could speed up this process and ease the ammount of requests needed using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently no, this is a gap in the API. You'll be happy to hear that we're working on some basic Groups features for [The Next SoundCloud](http://next.soundcloud.com), which, because it's also just an API client, means that we'll be finding and patching these holes very shortly.

Comment: hello and thanks in advance, just wondering if anything like this was already implemented! :o) cheers

Comment: Try `/tracks/:id/groups` (standard 'undocumented feature' warning applies here)